# Managing a website with more than 1000 images.

Tags: image, performance, web

I am having a static website with around 200 images in the gallery page right now. 
It becomes really difficult to organize and manage the media files.

And when I plan to expand and increase the images to around 1000. I feel like planning how to organize them should be my Step 1 before starting with the project.

Right now I'm placing all the \img folder on the hosting server. I Resize and Rename them manually. Sure its not the best approach.

What does other websites with multiple images do? Looking for a smarter alternative. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, off the top of my head, prefixing image-names can help a bunch, like home_facebooklogo.png, menu_screenshotsbutton.png. To make it more rigid, simply make folders for each page or component, like:

```
/img/menu/button_about.png
/img/home/mylogo.png
/img/about/myface.png
```

Not much of an answer, but that's what I do. Alternatively, a lot of webdesigners make use of one of the many products like Joomla, to help construct their websites, which make it easier to handle large quantities of images. But since you're here, I'm betting you're not bopping for that option :)

Comment: Thanks @Ultroman... I am following a nomenclature. But what i was more interested in knowing was, Is there any way to handle them apart from just renaming. for eg. some way i just need to upload a bunch of files and they are resized and renamed as you like. Not sure if thats possible.

Comment: I haven't seen a program like that. I'd use it if I had. So when you say "manage the media files", you don't mean programmatically; you mean the naming, resizing and creating thumbnails, right? That's the hard work of a webdesigner :D There are programs that can batch-resize images, and some even have naming-conventions, but they'll usually get resized to the same size all of them. If that's what you need, Fotosizer seems to fit the bill (just did a Google search for image batch resizer).